# OraOLEDB.Oracle listed in Management Studio but wrong version not available

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssms, linked-server, provider

I have a PC with SQL Server installed, in particular Management Studio 2008 R2 64 bit. Also Oracle OraOLEDB.Oracle provider has been installed but in 32 bit version. If I try to create a linked server with this provider it does not work and this is a correct behaviour I think. I cannot understand why I see OraOLEDB.Oracle listed between available providers if the correct version of OraOLEDB.Oracle (that is 64 bit) is not installed. Do you have any idea? 
Unfortunately I do not know how software has been installed, but I have to operate with this PC anyway. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Oracle documentation, both the 64 and 32 bit clients work on the 64 bit version of Windows.

[Here is the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/OLEDB/intro.htm#OLEDB122)

Comment: and when I use tnsping to check connectivity with the oracle db it works. The problem is that in Management Studio I am not able to create a linked server to that Oracle db using OraOLEDB.Oracle as provider (32bit).  While in a machine with the same settings plus the OraOLEDB.Oracle 64bit installed the linked server is working. I have no clue about why this happens